# Python: Strange list behaviour

Tags: python, list

So, I am playing around with Python trying to learn how to use it and I discovered something odd.  My code is:

```
list1 = range(0, 2)
list2 = range(2, 4)

comb = list1, list2

print comb
print list1

list1.append(list2)

print comb
print list1
```

the outputs are:

```
print comb   ---   ([0, 1], [2, 3])
print list1  ---   [0, 1]

print comb   ---   ([0, 1, [2, 3]], [2, 3])
print list1  ---   [0, 1, [2, 3]]
```

What seem to be happening is I am combining my two lists, which works fine.  But when I append `list2` into `list1` and re-print my `comb` list, the `comb` list has been updated with the newly appended `list1`.

What am I missing? Why does `comb` change when it has not been recalculated since the appending of `list1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`comb` contains *references* to `list1` and `list2` themselves, not copies of them.  Furthermore, this means that `comb[0]` is in fact `list1` and vice-vera.

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> list1 = range(0, 2)
>>> list2 = range(2, 4)
>>> comb = list1, list2
>>> id(list1)
28888960
>>> id(comb[0])
28888960
>>>
```

In the above example, notice how the ids of `list1` and `comb[0]` are the same.  What this tells you is that they both reference the same object in memory.  So, when you update one, the other will also be updated.

---

To fix the problem, make `comb` contain *copies* of `list1` and `list2` instead of references:

```
>>> list1 = range(0, 2)
>>> list2 = range(2, 4)
>>> # [:] creates a shallow copy of the lists.
>>> comb = list1[:], list2[:]
>>> id(list1)
28930176
>>> id(comb[0])
28931696
>>>
```

As you can see, the ids of `list1` and `comb[0]` are now different.  This means that they no longer reference the same object.

Answer (score 2):

`comb` is a tuple, with two *references* to the same list objects that the `list1` and `list2` names refer to.

When you appended `list2` to `list1`, you added another reference to that list to `list1`. Now you have *3* references to that list object. One in `list2`, another in `comb[1]` and a third in `list1[2]`.

Whenever you manipulate a list or dictionary or any other mutable object type in Python, all references to that object will reflect those changes, because you are dealing with just *one* object.

Picture objects as balloons, and names are labels, tied to the balloons with thread. The threads are references. You can tie multiple labels to a balloon, but you'd still have only *one* balloon, and if you popped the balloon all labels would be tied to the same piece of lifeless rubber.

Lists and tuples are just balloons with numbered labels taped onto them; those labels are tied to other objects. So `comb` is a balloon with two labels taped on, numbered 0 and 1. Those labels are tied to the *same* balloons `list1` and `list2` are tied to *as well*.

Answer (score 0):

`comb` holds *references* to `list1` and `list2`. Thus when you update `list1`, `comb` is updated as well.

If you want `comb` to hold a copy of the data from `list1` and `list2` instead of a reference, try:

```
comb = (list1[:], list2[:])
```

Answer (score 0):

`comb` is composed of `list1` and `list2`. Mutating `list1` doesn't change this, and it appears that `comb` has changed when in reality, it is still exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine had this the other day. This effect stems from your

```
comb = list1, list2
```

You need to use

```
comb = list(list1 + list2)
```

to actually copy the list, cf. http://www.precheur.org/python/copy_list and http://od-eon.com/blogs/bogdan/python-assignment-value-or-reference/

Comment: comb = list(list1 + list2)